# How to save the captured image in streamlit

Tags: android, python-3.x, button, session-state, streamlit

I developed one streamlit application in that I will crop the images and preview the same but I don't know how to save the cropped image

I need help to save the image which I cropped and I should able to see the image when I press previous and next.

Comment: You can use a library such as Pillow or OpenCV to crop the image and save it on the filesystem.

Comment: No I am developing an web app based on streamlit only so I need to save by using streamlit itself

Comment: Then you will need to use a file storage library such as "io", "os", etc.

import streamlit as st
import io
from PIL import Image

image_data = st.file_uploader("Upload an image")
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
cropped_image = image.crop((left, top, right, bottom))

if st.button("write text here"):
    image_bytes = io.BytesIO()
    cropped_image.save(image_bytes, format="PNG")
    image_data = image_bytes.getvalue()
    with open("cropped_image.png", "wb") as f:
        f.write(image_data)
    st.success("write text here)